# Can I change the default Gimp transparent background to white?

Tags: gimp, transparency, background

I'm using Gimp 2. The default grid-style transparent background makes it incredibly difficult to get a sense of what the image will actually look like, when I finally display it over a background. Is there a way I can make the transparent background display as something other than the default grid, for example as a simple white background?

Comment: Hi Josef, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Better answer here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/134081/gimp-how-to-edit-a-sngle-layer-transparency-using-a-white-background/134083#134083

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, that would be very easy, I just opened up Gimp 2 my self and tried it out to make sure! :p Anyway, in the layers panel, right click and choose New Layer.

[image: Screenshot]

Then make sure you select White for the Layer Fill Type.

[image: Screenshot]

Now, click OK and move the new white layer to the bottom of all the current layers.

[image: Screenshot]

To change the layer color, select it and just paint it in with any color you want!

Hope this helped.

Comment: So obvious and easy, how could I not think about it... Thanks !

Answer (score 6):

Adding a background layer is a nice way to try different backgrounds.

The more boring way would be to set the transparency style in the display preferences, "[...] either to a different type of checkerboard, or to solid black, white, or gray":

[image: GIMP image window display preferences]

This is also described in GIMP's [docs](https://docs.gimp.org/2.8/en/gimp-pimping.html#gimp-prefs-display).

Comment: This is the more 'proper' way of doing it. Also found at https://superuser.com/a/353968/389451